# Blazegraph - Full text search analyzer configuration

Tags: lucene, full-text-search, sparql, blazegraph

I'm using Blazegraph 2.1.5 and I'd like to perform full text search using http://www.bigdata.com/rdf/search# service.
The namespace configuration is:

```
com.bigdata.rdf.store.AbstractTripleStore.textIndex=true
com.bigdata.rdf.store.AbstractTripleStore.axiomsClass=com.bigdata.rdf.axioms.NoAxioms
com.bigdata.rdf.sail.isolatableIndices=true
com.bigdata.rdf.sail.truthMaintenance=false
com.bigdata.rdf.store.AbstractTripleStore.justify=false
com.bigdata.rdf.sail.namespace=fst-test
com.bigdata.rdf.store.AbstractTripleStore.quads=true
com.bigdata.namespace.fst-test.lex.com.bigdata.btree.BTree.branchingFactor=400
com.bigdata.journal.Journal.groupCommit=false
com.bigdata.namespace.fst-test.spo.com.bigdata.btree.BTree.branchingFactor=1024
com.bigdata.rdf.store.AbstractTripleStore.geoSpatial=true
com.bigdata.rdf.store.AbstractTripleStore.statementIdentifiers=false
```

Considering the following triple

`<http://example.org/data/1> rdfs:label  "Available" .`

I do the query

```
prefix bds: <http://www.bigdata.com/rdf/search#>
select ?s ?p ?o
where {
?o bds:search "avalable" .
?s ?p ?o .
}
```

expecting a result containing the triple.
However, I get no results.

Basically, I would like to enable something like fuzzy string searching.
I guess it could be related to the analyzer configuration, but I'm not able to figure it properly.
Do you have any suggestions?

Thanks a lot.

Comment: What happens when you give just "ava" or "ava*"?